# Homework problems

Tags: discussion

What's our policy for homework problems?  I see people tagging them with the "homework" tag, but should we have a rule about it?

Stack Overflow's ["How to ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for reference

Comment: I think that we should assume that the SO FAQ applies unless we explicitly decide otherwise.  Perhaps our 'FAQ' page should include a link to [The Official SOFU FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)?

Comment: make that an answer reemrevnivek. I am 100% behind you and would like to up-vote you in a more substantial way.

Comment: If the colleges had less internal assessment and more emphasis on external EXAMs this problem wont be so bad .

Answer (score 7):

Given the SO FAQ homework section is mainly focused on software and lines of code, I do not think in its current state it is relevant to electronics and robotics.

Students asking blatant homework questions with no thought or attempt are generally immediately obvious, and cannot generally be answered to any meaningful level.

On the other hand, students working on projects and getting stuck with situations will be asking "work" type problems as they are building/fixing/repairing something so their questions can easily be answered by others and will only aid the students development.

On the flip side, even hobbist or professional could ask questions that fit in either bucket, the first being a new area that has not been researched via google beforehand or the later stuck on a real problem.

So in my opinion, I think we need a toned down version of what is on the SO FAQ more suited to electronic hardware.  Furthermore the issue of homework questions is just not as significant.

Comment: I think the rules apply to hardware and software in this case often. sometimes someone just needs a command they did not know about in software, sometimes you need a different hardware configuration you did not know about in hardware. In both cases you could probably use very many basic building blocks to reach the same end.

Comment: there are gonna be cases where someone uploads a schematic and asks for the output voltage of a 12 opamp network that has no real value and is doing it for homework, and in those cases answers explaining methods to approach the problem always help.

Comment: In the old days before they had degrees for dumb people the assignments would NOT get you through because you always had to get 50% in the exam to pass.That meant that answering someones homework question was not cheating because to pass he or she still had to get 50% in the final to pass.